# TNS 12545, 00515 - NOT RUNNING tnslsnr

Tags: oracle

I have a linux server with oracle 10 g release 10.1.0.3.0 and an application based on oracle name NMS5ux.
I needed to change its net. settings(ip, D.G.W).

1- So when its oracle and NMS were up, i change net. settings by YAST, but i forget to update /etc/hosts file. May be the fault is that i change them when oracle is started not stoped and i have to update /etc/hosts file but didn't.
The NMS got locked.

2- To solve the condition i revert the changes to original setting by YAST again, but no sesns result, software is liked to be locked.

3- So i log out the application and stop oracle and NMS to get ride of condition.

4- Then i decide to start process, because i think that no problem, i changed back all of settings and i will restart the process. But till now oracle process not start up. I couldn't test NMS start up, because it based on oracle and depended on it.

Here i will send photo of faulty oracle start up process. For comparison i sent the photo of this process when it work correctly.

Refer to TNS 12545, 00515 it seems that it lost the host, but refer  to tcp protocol connection it search host by name not ip, and i didn't change name. Off course some where it must take name to address resolution, i check all of tnsnames.ora , listner.ora , sqlnet.ora  , non of them has ip address, just in listner.ora  ‘HOST’ is introduce by name not ip. I think that resolution is take place in /etc/hosts that i didn't change it.

In report before some number about byte numbers
it show twi SQL line that seems ok, but in RUNNING part show that tnslsnr is NOT RUNNING, and finally show that oracle process check FAILED.

The important thing is that i set back Network settings to origin,  so why system didn't go back to normal operation?

I appreciate any advises.

Comment: That's quite hard to read/follow, but it looks like `nms5lxgr` used to resolve to an IP address and now it doesn't. So "change back the network setting" didn't, it seems. You could change listner.ora and tnsnames.ora to use the new name/IP; but presumably you were changing the network settings for a reason. Anyway, off-topic for this site either way.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, really it was the cause, i check the /etc/hosts file and change it  to proper content.   Because my host name was change beyond my expectation, so i correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I just need to change the Net. settings, and just did that change in my server and quickly i change them  back to original settings. Means that no changes. But after that i cant start oracle process Any more

In report based  on connection protocol ‘tcp’, it seems that HOST is introduce by name not ip, and i didnt nothing with host name.
Is it necessary to check listner.ora and tnsnames.ora that may be they were destroyed?!
I will check them.!

Finally it has been solved. I changed the ip using YAST, but control the /etc/hosts if needed edit manually. Every things went well,

Thanks a lot to EdStevens, his idea about name resolution subject is an important point to break the fault.

Comment: This is not an answer but a continuation of the discussion. As for "it seems that HOST is introduce by name not ip, and i didnt nothing with host name."   all network traffic is routed by IP.  If you are referneceing the host name (as you should) then the network will consult the DNS listing to resolve that name to its IP address.  Did you update DNS to reflect the new IP address for your host name?

Comment: If you connect directly to the server with ssh, as the owner of the oracle installation, then initiate a BEQ connection like this:     sqlplus / as sysdba  then the network will not be involved in getting your database started, though it will still matter for routing client requests.

Comment: I didn't understand yor suggestion to initiate a BEQ connection? Pls explain more.

Comment: Never mind,  On further reading of your initial post, it appears that your database is started. But overall your initial post and discription is very confusing.  Instead of trhing to describe it, you should update your post and and copy and paste your command sessions to show _exactly_ what you are doing and _exactly_ how oracle is responding.

Comment: Thanks EdStevens,   I tried to format the question in better explanation, i decide to add some photo about oracle start up report  but it couldn't be done!

Comment: Excuse me i want to add a photo of oracle process, but system sent an error that it needs 10 reputation, how can i do it? I do oracle start up by a file, just double click it, and see the result report. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Pleeeeze, no photos or screen shots.   What did I say in my last post?  "update your post and and copy and paste your command sessions "  Copying text out of a command window is very easy.  I will leave it as an exercise for the student to google the process.  And since you will be pasting _text_ into your opening post, reputation points will not matter.

Comment: This entire thread has grown beyond the normal format of SO.  It might be better discussed on Oracle's database discussion forum, which allows for a more open-ended discussion.  https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/3063-general_questions1

Answer (score 0):

I have checked all of the *.ora files. There isn't any ip address information there.
I concluded that name to address resolution is take place in /etc/hosts file.(there isn't DNS server in our network). And i didn't update it when i change the ip settings. So may be the first hang of server could be normal, but i quickly return them back, so no change in ip address. But why oracle is became faulty till now?
Another question: is it so important to Shutdown oracle when we decide to change network settings?

Comment: The _database_ doesn't know anything about the networking.  It is quite happy to run with no network at all.  It is the _listener_ and the _clients_ that have to be concerned with networking issues.

Comment: based on listener.log file, for TNS:00515, it explain that host or object fir tcp connection does not exist. I read the listener.ora , for tcp connection HOST is defined by name and i didn't change the nam by myself at all.  But it attract my attention, i check the YAST, is is as i want to be, check it in cmd. With hostname, and ifconfig eth0 command. The result as the settings in YAST, so is OK.

Comment: BUT BUT, i check the /etc/hosts   and   /etc/hostsYAST2save, they are strange. For current ip the name resolved to a hostname that i didn't predict.  So obviously HOST name that is in listner.ora is not exist in name resolving file. For ensurance i ping my hostname as in YAST and listener.ora ,  ping report error unknown. But ping withe the strange name belong to /etc/hosts file, so ping first resolve it to my ip address, the send ping normal report. At know i find that the name resolution does not work as my sense. So the root cause is found.

Comment: Now the question is that how /etc/hosts or any name resolved file is filled: whether manually or automatically from YAST?  Thanks for any advises.

Comment: There aren't  DHCP and DNS here.

Comment: I changed the ip using YAST, but control the /etc/hosts if needed change manually. Every things went well.